# Adding security on transport layer level

Tags: security, callout, soap, wsdl2apex

Is there any documentation or reference on how to add username and password to the transport layer when making an apex callout to consume a SOAP based service?

Comment: In the HTTP headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add custom headers as described in [SOAP Services: Defining a Class from a WSDL Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm), as demonstrated below:

```
docSample.DocSamplePort stub = new docSample.DocSamplePort();
stub.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();

//Setting a basic authentication header

stub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization', 'Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==');

//Setting a cookie header
stub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Cookie', 'name=value');

//Setting a custom HTTP header
stub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('myHeader', 'myValue');

String input = 'This is the input string';
String output = stub.EchoString(input);
```

Comment: I guess you add credentials with header in this way. Correct? The transport layer to the external system is encrypted.

Comment: I hit the service endpoint using soap ui and I get a correct response. I include only username and password in soap ui. But when I hit from salesforce I include username and password in http header like how you described. But I get an exception that the service denied my request. Any idea why?

Comment: @SfdcBat I'd have to see a sample of the successful request to know for sure. Perhaps include it in your question?

Comment: Please see my edit sfdcfox!

Comment: I get this error: System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: [ISS.0088.9164] Access to WSDescriptor MU650_ECM_Unity_Order_v1.webservices:order_wsd_pro denied. faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=https://xyzz

Comment: @SfdcBat I'm sorry, I realized I missed your comment. The inputHttpHeaders_x feature should work, but you'll need to make sure your headers are correct.

Comment: Hi , no worries. I realized that I was using my dev edition to do that and it does not allow the connection. I tried to make a callout from a Sandbox and I got - System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.

Comment: @SfdcBat - From that message I take away that the webservice has not upgraded their TLS and only accepts v1. If that is the case you will not be able to connect to it as v1 has been disabled by Salesforce and pretty much everywhere else for security concerns: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1 - If the server upgrades their encryption you will be able to use it, until then your are out of luck

Comment: @Eric can I ask the service provider to upgrade their TLS? How hard is it to upgrade? Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @SfdcBat - Difficulty all depends on their architecture so it is hard to say. Also, their policies on testing and validation may increase the effort required significantly. As for asking, it never hurts, but I would not expect a quick turn around except for the fact that they most likely already have plans for it in their pipeline or they risk becoming obsolete pretty quickly and no-one will connect to them. Of course I may be misreading the error message you provided so get a second opinion before throwing in the towel.